# Using a defined jQuery var in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm learning jQuery and I'm trying to create some kind of livechecker with focusout in jQuery. I need to use some data out of the current PHP session. This is straightforward etc but the data I need to get out of the session is set in an multidimensional array, so to specify which item I need I use the current focusout object. And as such I find myself in this situation that I cant seem to solve:

```
  $( "#formjquery" )
    .focusout(function(e) {
        var currInput = ($(e.target).attr("name")).replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        var currAntwoord = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['aSommenArray'][currInput]['A'])?>;
        console.log(currAntwoord);
    })
```

This obviously doesn't work because I can't use the jQuery var in the PHP echo but is there some way to do this?

```
<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['aSommenArray'][?>currInput<?php]['A'])?>
```

also doesn't work but I expected as much.

I know I should be able to do this if I first send it with an ajax call to use it in PHP but I hope there is an faster way to do this but I haven't found one yet.

Maybe the answer for this is as straightforward as an answer can be, but I haven't found an answer yet.

Thanks in advance and happy coding

Comment: The first thing to learn when trying to learn jquery is that it is spelled "jquery" not "jquerry".

Comment: @Isma Woops, ye ok thats a misstep, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right, you can do something like:

```
// here you store all data from aSommenArray
var someAnswers = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['aSommenArray']?>;

$( "#formjquery" )
    .focusout(function(e) {
        var currInput = ($(e.target).attr("name")).replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        // here you access data from someAnswers
        var currAntwoord = someAnswers[currInput]['A'];
        console.log(currAntwoord);
    })
```

Comment: O shit im such an stupid that I didnt try it.. so if I understand correct i can litteraly just put the multidimensional array in an variable?

Comment: Sure, you can. And then access any key from it. But as the data from `someAnswers` can be faked on client side, you need additional check on server, of course if it is requred.

Comment: Well yep I tried it this works for me. Well i feel stupid asking this now but I learned from it. thanks a lot i didnt know i could litterally parse the full array in a variable, But if i understand correctly I can even just parse the `$_SESSION` itself in a variable?

Comment: Yes, you can add any variable to `json_encode` and output it.

Comment: Yes I still need to get the server side check when the form is submitted but thanks a lot ill accept the answer in 5 min becouse the question answer timer. And I underestemated what I can put trough the json encoder